# Plot with varying yrange without a log scale or an inset

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question was closed yesterday because of a misunderstanding.

I have the figure below and want to zoom around y=-.1 to y=.4 so n=2..4 can be clearly seen. How to "zoom in" on that range?
[image]

If n=1 is not present the other curves look this:

[image]
I DO NOT want to use an inset rather I want to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: If you set `Axes.set_xlim` to `(2, 4)`, does the output differ from what you need ?

Comment: Your second image seems to indicate you'd want something like [`ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthresh=250)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/symlog_demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use two adjacent subplots (`sharex='all` to remove upper `xticks` & `xticklabels`, `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)` to squish them together), then you have just to be careful in setting the *y* limits in the two subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0.00001, np.pi-0.00001, 201)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='all')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

ax1.plot(t, 1/np.sin(t)**2)
ax1.plot(t,   np.sin(t)**2)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 3)

ax0.semilogy(t, 1/np.sin(t)**2)
ax0.set_ylim(ymin=3)

plt.show()
```